# Multiple problems with exscript when I use ssh: delayed outputs, delays in initiating the connection, authorization problems

Tags: ssh, paramiko

Here is my code:

```
conn = SSH2()
conn.connect(host)
conn.authenticate(account)
print (conn.response)
conn.send('enable 8\n')                            <--------------first problem: execute("enable 8') does not work here. Can't understand why. I have to use send
conn.execute('somepassword') 
print (conn.response)
conn.execute('term len 0')                        <--------------fore some reason the output for this command makes it to the outputs list that I am creating below
print (conn.response)
for command in commands:
    print "Executing command", command
       try:
            conn.execute(command)
            print (conn.response)
      except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            output="Unsupported command or timeout"

        outputs.append(output)
```

To recap:
-this is not mentioned above but I have to start the script, it will fail in my first run (timeout) then the second attempt succeeds
-why is the authorization not working with execute?
-why do the output of my commands seem to be delayed ? My understanding is that every time when I run an "execute('command') the exscript waits for the output and only then it proceeds with executing the next command.
Let's say I have the commands 1,2,3,4
sometimes I see the outputs of command 2 and 3 stored together, they look like they were received by one conn.response while the previous conn.response is empty

any help with the above will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was discussed at the [exscript mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exscript/9-kl2h9CWV8). For completeness I will answer here, too.

First problem:
For some reason the os guesser didn't recognize the device correctly and therefore used the generic driver, which didn't work.
This can be fixed by [filing a bug](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/issues) or setting the driver manually (in that case ios).

Second problem:
Please don't ever execute passwords (`execute('somepassword')`)! That will likely result in a mess.
Use exscripts authentication / authorization mechanisms instead.

The following should work:

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2

account = read_login()

conn = SSH2()
# setting driver manually would be:
# conn = SSH2(manual_driver="ios")
conn.connect("host")
conn.authenticate(account)
conn.send('enable 8\n')

# if authorization password differs from login password
# you have to set it in account instance
account.set_authorization_password("<enable password>")

conn.app_authorize(account)

conn.autoinit()

outputs = []

for command in commands:
    print "Executing command", command
       try:
            conn.execute(command)
            output = conn.response
      except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            output = "Unsupported command or timeout"

        outputs.append(output)
```

This could be shorter, if exscripts high level API would be used.